# How to filter divs with only one data attribute using multiple dropdown selects in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, filter, tags

I am trying to filter div elements, using multiple drop-down `<select>` elements. I need to store keywords in one line, for example:

```
data-keywords="All, Red, Car"
```

This function needs to stay dynamic, because it is unclear what
drop-down selects and what tags we are going to have.

I have developed everything up until second drop-down select.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

It works with one drop-down select, but if I try to select multiple drop-down selects it breaks.

```js
$("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $(".item.visible").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
  });
});

//Filter items
$("select").change(function() {
  // var filter = $(this).val();
  var filter = $.map($("select").toArray(), function(e) {
    return $(e).val();
  }).join(", ");
  filterList(filter);
  console.log(filter);
});

//Filter function
function filterList(value) {
  var list = $(".item");
  $(list).fadeOut("fast");

  $(".items")
    .find(".item[data-keywords*=" + value + "]")
    .addClass("visible")
    .each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay(200).slideDown("fast");
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container filters">
  <input id="searchInput" type="text" value="" placeholder="search" />

  <select name="selector" id="selector">
    <option value="All">Color</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
  <select name="selector" id="selector">
    <option value="All">Item</option>
    <option value="Car">Car</option>
    <option value="Ship">Ship</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="container items">
  <div class="item" data-keywords="All, Green, Car">
    <p>This is my item</p>
    <p>Green car</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-keywords="All, Red, Ship">
    <p>This is my item</p>
    <p>Red ship</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-keywords="All, Red, Car">
    <p>This is my item</p>
    <p>Red car</p>
  </div>
</div>
```